# VMware Workstation 16.2.4 Pro: Some keys are not sent to the virtual machine, whatever operating system it has

Tags: 22.04, virtualization, vmware-workstation

VMware® Workstation 16 Pro 16.2.4 build-20089737
Host machine: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (Upgraded from 20.04 LTS).
Virtual machine: any.

The Windows-Logo key, the ctrl+alr+del keys, the stamp-r-sist key (for the screenshots) and I don't know what others are not sent to the virtual machine, even if it has focus and is full screen.
The host machine reacts to pressing those keys but not the VM.
This problem arose after upgrading the host system from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
Why? How do I resolve?
I tried reinstalling VMware from 0 but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is Wayland, with Xorg I have solved it.

Comment: As of today, On Ubuntu 23.04 and VM Workstation 17.0.2, this only solution is to switch back to XOrg.